# Mozilla Firefox error "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, php, json

When I am trying to get response from my API I am getting  **JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data** this error in **Mozilla Firefox** Browser but not in **Chrome** browser.

```
            $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: myApiUrl,
                    data: data,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(result)
                    { alert("success");}
                  });
```

Note : assume that myApiUrl variable contains my url and 
data contains my parameters.

Following is my Json Response

```
{"type":"Sale","status":1,"transaction_id":"T4U_122a668896_4bdadcc57","ErrorMSG":"Success","ErrorCode":"00","passive_data":"####aaaa","total":"10.47","time":"31-01-2017 09:56:55"}
```

How should I overcome that problem?

Comment: Can you post the JSON as well?

Comment: can you add a snippet of your data object?

Comment: var data= { total:grandtotal, customer_firstname:firstname, customer_lastname:lastname, customer_email:email, customer_phone:phone, bank_id:bank_id, gateway:gateway}

Comment: Is "var data=" also part of the response? I can not believe that the JSON response you have written in your post (not in your comment but in your post) is the actual output Firefox is giving you. What is the EXACT return value Firefox gives back to you in the success callback?

Comment: @John Smith "var data=" is not part of response. Actual response was null but im getting **null** in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type: 'POST'`. If it still doesn't work, try using  `async: false`

Comment: type: 'POST' used already and when Im using async: false gives **null** as response.

Answer (score -1):

Like the above answer says, we can change async parameter in `XMLHttpRequet.open(`) like

sample.open("GET", url, **false**). from sample.open("GET", url, **true**)

I met this bug only when running, but when debugging it is good.